# Are no "rel" attribute backlinks dofollow or nofollow?

Tags: links, nofollow, alexa, dofollow

I have signed up for Alexa's one month free and they gave me an option to list two extra links to my site.

These extra two links do not have a `rel` attribute, although the main link (1st) to my site has a `rel="nofollow"` value.

Does this mean that these extra two links are `dofollow` by default or `nofollow`?

Here is [my site's Alexa page](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/7quran.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a link has a `rel="nofollow"` attribute, there is `nofollow` link. In other case, this is a `dofollow` link. Two links are thus `dofollow`.

Comment: Note that there are other factors than can determine whether a link is actually considered _dofollow_ or not. The robots META tag or `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header or robots.txt file or intermediary script can all prevent the link from being considered _dofollow_ by search engines.